# Trouble finding PHP syntax error using echo to create amp-html code

Tags: php, amp-html

I am attempting to echo some amp-html code using PHP

```
<?php
echo "<section>";
echo "<h3>$title[$i]</h3>";
echo "<amp-video controls width="560" height="315" layout="responsive">";
echo "<source src="https: //example.com/videos/";
    echo $filename[$i];
    echo "_HD.mp4 type="video / mp4 / > ";
    echo " < sourcesrc = "https://example.com/videos/";
    echo $filename[$i];
    echo '"__HD.webm" type="video/webm"/>';
    echo "<div fallback><p>This browser does not support the video element.</p></div>";
    echo "</amp-video>";
    echo "</section>";
?>
```

I have been unable to find a syntax error, what a I missing? Is there an easier way than using echo.?

**Update**:
Ive edited the code according to the suggestions, but its still throwing up a blank page: Here is the full code:

```
<?php
        // Create connection
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xx","xxxx","xxxx");

       // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    //Get number of rows

$sql="SELECT id,title,filename FROM videos";

    $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $i=1;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $id[$i] = $row['id'];
        $title[$i] = $row['title'];
        $filename[$i] = $row['filename'];
        $i++;
    }
    // Loop through the results from the database

    for ($i = 1; $i <=count($id); $i++)
    {
?>

<section>
    <h3><?php echo $title[$i];?></h3>
    <amp-video controls width="560" height="315" layout="responsive">
        <source src="https: //example.com/videos/<?php echo $filename[$i];?>_HD.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="https://example.com/videos/<?php echo $filename[$i];?>__HD.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <div fallback><p>This browser does not support the video element.</p></div>
    </amp-video>
</section>
}
</amp-accordion>
```

Comment: It seems that you are using double quotes inside double quotes in multiple places like here `"_HD.mp4 type="video / mp4 / > "`. Try replacing the internal double quotes with single quotes.

Comment: You also don't need to echo every line. You could do one echo and concatenate, or only open PHP when you need to output. Here's how I'd write it, https://3v4l.org/qOKDH, I also tweaked some of the attributes, I think you had some typos.

Comment: Are you using some AMP Validator Tool at all?  Is your page fully amp valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With so little actual PHP output in your code it might be easier and more readable to just drop out of PHP to output the HTML.

```
        // Create connection
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xx","xxxx","xxxx");

       // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    //Get number of rows

$sql="SELECT id,title,filename FROM videos";

    $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>

<section>
    <h3><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h3>
    <amp-video controls width="560" height="315" layout="responsive">
        <source src="https: //example.com/videos/<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>_HD.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="https://example.com/videos/<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>__HD.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <div fallback><p>This browser does not support the video element.</p></div>
    </amp-video>
</section>
<?php
    }  // end of while
?>
</amp-accordion>
<?php
```

Comment: I've updated the code as suggested with a drop out of PHP to output the HTML, but its still throwing up a blank page. See the full code in my updated edited post.

Comment: That can't be all of your code. If it is the error is because you never close your `for` loop.

Comment: How would I close the loop in this instance without happening to resort to using echo? Is there a better suited loop for this?

Comment: I updated my answer and removed one of your loops which wasn't even needed. You did not include your `<amp-accordion>` starting tag so I can only guess that it was earlier in your code. I did leave in the closing tag since you had included it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is indeed the use of your syntax. What you should try to do is to use single quotes  when you do an echo of html and anything else you may add inside the html you use double quotes.

```
  <?php
echo '<section>';
echo '<h3>$title[$i]</h3>';
echo '<amp-video controls width="560" height="315" layout="responsive">';
echo '<source src="https://example.com/videos/'.$filename[$i].'_HD.mp4" type="video / mp4 / >"';
    echo '<source src="https://example.com/videos/'.$filename[$i].'__HD.webm" type="video/webm"/>"';
    echo '<div fallback><p>This browser does not support the video element.</p></div>';
    echo '</amp-video>';
    echo '</section>';
?>
```

This way it is a lot easier to spot the syntax errors, because the page will either display what it must display or display the code.